# For all non-negative integers $n$ such that $n ≥ 8$, there exist non-negative integers $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $3a_n+5b_n = n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

The solution to this question below is a bit confusing to me. If anyone would be kind enough to explain how the inductive claim works and why it is true for $3a_{n+1} + 5b_{n+1} = n+1$ This would help me a lot, thank you in advance.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpM4X.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MROOt.jpg)

Comment: Outside links are frowned upon. Please put all relevant info in the question itself, and use LaTeX formatting to improve readability. Also, your title could be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

- $A_{8}=\{3,5\}$
- $A_{9}=\{3,3,3\}$
- $A_{10}=\{5,5\}$
- $A_{n}=A_{n-3}\cup\{3\}$

Answer (score 2):

Claim : For every natural number $n\ge 8$, there exist nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$ with $3a+5b=n$

Base case $n=8$ : Take $a=1$ and $b=1$

Suppose, we have $3a+5b=n$

For $b\ge 1$, we have $3(a+2)+5(b-1)=3a+5b+1=n+1$

For $a\ge 3$, we have $3(a-3)+5(b+2)=3a+5b+1=n+1$

So, the induction step works whenever $b\ge 1$ or $a\ge 3$. The remaining case is $a<3$ and $b=0$, but the corresponding numbers are $0,3,6$, which are smaller than $8$