# Correct Way of Reaching Inductive Goal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

To provide full context of the practice question I'm attempting, it is as follows:

> For every integer n such that n ≥ 8, there exist nonnegative integers a<sub>n</sub> and b<sub>n</sub> such that 3a<sub>n</sub> + 5b<sub>n</sub> = n.
>
> Write a proof of the claim using the strong form of mathematical induction with the integer 10 as breakpoint — such that that n = 8, n = 9 and n = 10 would all be considered in the basis.

This is my attempt at the proof, but I can't seem to get past applying the I.H. in order to reach my goal in the inductive step.

> **Basis** 
>   If n = 8, then 3a<sub>8</sub> + 5b<sub>8</sub> = 8 
>   To satisfy the above, set a<sub>8</sub> = 1 and b<sub>8</sub> = 1, therefore 3(1) + 5(1) = 3 + 5 = 8
>
> If n = 9, then 3a<sub>9</sub> + 5b<sub>9</sub> = 9 
>   Set a<sub>9</sub> = 3 and b<sub>9</sub> = 0, therefore 3(3) + 5(0) = 9 + 0 = 9
>
> If n = 10, then 3a<sub>10</sub> + 5b<sub>10</sub> = 10
>
> Set a<sub>10</sub> = 0 and b<sub>10</sub> = 2, therefore 3(0) + 5(2) = 0 + 10 = 10
>
> **Inductive Hypothesis** 
>   Let k be an integer such that k ≥ 10. It is necessary and sufficient to use the following:
>
> - Inductive Hypothesis: 3a<sub>n</sub> + 5b<sub>n</sub> = n for every integer n such that 8 ≤ n ≤ k.
>
> **Inductive Claim** 
>  3a<sub>k+1</sub> + 5b<sub>k+1</sub> = k+1
>
> Since for every integer n, 8 ≤ n ≤ k, there are ak-2 and bk-2, then it follows that:
>
> 3a<sub>k-2</sub> + 5b<sub>k-2</sub> = k - 2 (**Starting Point**)
>
> ..
>
> ..
>
> ..
>
> 3a<sub>k+1</sub> + 5b<sub>k+1</sub> = k+1 (**Goal**)

Now I know where to begin and the goal I need to reach for my inductive step but I am unsure as to how to reach my goal.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Am I missing something?  Is it not sufficient to set $a_n = a_{n-3}+1$ and $b_n = b_{n-3}$?

Comment: You can have a look at [For all non-negative integers $n$ such that $n ≥ 8$, there exist non-negative integers $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $3a_n+5b_n = n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2080814). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%243a_n%20%2B%205b_n%3D%20n%24&p=1). More tips on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: Simply 3 + 5 = 8, 3×3 = 9, 5x2 = 10 is sufficient to establish the base step.  Toss in a 5×0 or a 3×0 if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

3 + 5 = 8, 3×3 = 9, 5x2 = 10

The next step is 11 = 8 + 3.
Since 8 has been answered, an answer for 11 is apparent.
Likewise for n > 10, by induction hypothesis,
there is a solution for n - 3, so a solution for n.

Exercise.  Show every integer >= 8 is a multiple of 3
or 5 + a multiple of 3 or 10 + a multiple of 3
as an immediate result of the above proof.