# Prove that any positive integer greater than or equal to 9 can be written as a sum of the form a + b where a is a multiple of 5 and b is even.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Prove that any positive integer greater or equal to 9 can be written as a sum of the form + where a is a multiple of 5
and  is even.
I know I need K+1 but I'm not sure how that factors in. But, I also modeled out the problem and the last digit of  a cycles between 5 and (1)0 while b cycles between 4, 0, 6, 2, 8. Does anyone know what this means.

Comment: Hint:  If $n$ is even, there is no problem (why)?  If $n$ is odd, $n-5$ is even.

Comment: Note:  I assume you meant to write that $a,b$ were both positive.

Comment: If you start writing out representations for $10,11,12, \ldots$ you should see a pattern you can use. You might have to go as far as $20$ or $30$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @EthanBolker so I modeled it out, what do I do with that sort of information.

Comment: You can write up that model as the answer to your question. You don't need induction. How would you express $1001$ and $1002$ and $1006$?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080814

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For all non-negative integers $n$ such that $n ≥ 8$, there exist non-negative integers $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $3a_n+5b_n = n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080814/for-all-non-negative-integers-n-such-that-n-%e2%89%a5-8-there-exist-non-negative-in)

Answer (score 1):

Let N be an even number. a + b = N. We can split this up into 2 cases + check when the condition can't be passed because the numbers are too small.

5 doesn't pass since it's not even. 6 Doesn't pass because you can't get your even number as 5 + 1 = 6. 5 + 2 = 7 passes but 8 does not since 5 + 3 (3 is odd).

9 is the smallest number where both conditions hold. The proof can be split into 2 cases:

Where N is even and where N is odd.

Case 1: When N is even. a + b is even when b is even, hence a must be even (since an even number minus an even number must be even). 10 is a multiple of 5 and is even hence Fix 10 as your a. Hence you can form your other number b (the one that has to be a multiple of 5) by taking that your needed number - 10 and you will also get an even number. Hence, you can get any even number for b so case scenario one is done.

Case 2: When N is odd. One scenario when a + b is odd is when an even number + an odd number. Pick any odd number you want (>= 9). Subtract 5 (one of the two numbers you require to be a multiple of 5) and you will always get an even number as your 2nd number.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n = 2k + 1$. Then $5t + 2s$ runs through all the odd numbers greater or equal to $5$ by induction with $t$ odd. If $n = 2k$, take $5 \times 2 \times a + 2b$, and it runs through all the even numbers greater or equal to $10$ by induction.